# Perl Regex with eval and late expression doesn't seem to execute twice (unless EVAL'd)

Tags: regex, perl

#### Note: Follow-Up posted as response to this question below.

I have a subroutine that uses regular expressions to parse a string into a series of chunks, and pass those chunks back in a list.  The string is packed in the format of one 32 bit integer in network order signifying the length of the item, followed by the item, repeated an unknown number of times.  If one were creating this string from a list `@samples`, it might look like this:

```
my $string  = pack 'NA*' x scalar @samples, map { length($_), $_ } @samples;
```

The basic parsing routine using Regex looks about like this:

```
my $parser = qr/
    ^ (?:
        (.{4})                          (?{ ($chunklen) = unpack( 'N', $^N ); })
        ((??{ qr~.{$chunklen}~s }))     (?{ push @chunks, $^N; })
    )+ $
/xs;
```

The first time it is invoked, it works flawlessly.  The second time, and all subsequent times, it does not work at all.  This example, with various points of debug output:

```
use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw/ time /;
use Data::Dumper;
use v5.10;

for ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    print "Try $_\n";
    my @samples = ( time, rand(10000), time );
    my $string  = pack 'NA*' x scalar @samples, map { length($_), $_ } @samples;
    print Dumper parse $string;
    print "\n";
}


sub parse($) {
    my ( $text ) = @_;
    my (@chunks, $chunklen);
    my $parser = qr/
        ^ (?:
            (.{4})                          (?{ ($chunklen) = unpack( 'N', $^N ); say $chunklen })
            ((??{ qr~.{$chunklen}~s }))     (?{ push @chunks, $^N; say $^N })
        )+ $
    /xs;

    unless ( $text =~ $parser ) {
        die 'bad parse';
    }

    print Dumper \@chunks;

    return @chunks;
}
```

produces the following output

```
Try 1
16
1425057728.71843
16
1491.39404296875
16
1425057728.71843
$VAR1 = [
          '1425057728.71843',
          '1491.39404296875',
          '1425057728.71843'
        ];
$VAR1 = '1425057728.71843';
$VAR2 = '1491.39404296875';
$VAR3 = '1425057728.71843';

Try 2
16
1425057728.71903
16
2074.27978515625
16
1425057728.71903
$VAR1 = [];
```

Note that @chunks somehow is not populated the second time, even though the values were found appropriately.

### Why don't it run more than once?

Things I have tried that did not work:

1. Storing `$parser` as a string, and compiling when it was tested
2. Returning the lazy expression `(??{ ... })` as a string and having it compiled later
3. Removing everything from a subroutine and calling it inline in the loop

The one thing I tried that did allow it to parse more than once was putting the whole thing in a quoted eval, like so:

```
sub parse($) { return eval q!
    my ( $text ) = @_;
    my (@chunks, $chunklen);
    my $parser = qr/
        ^ (?:
            (.{4})                          (?{ ($chunklen) = unpack( 'N', $^N ) })
            ((??{ qr~.{$chunklen}~s }))     (?{ push @chunks, $^N })
        )+ $
    /xs;

    unless ( $text =~ $parser ) {
        die 'bad parse';
    }

    return @chunks; !;
}
```

If we run that through the same testing body, with all the debug output removed, we see the following:

```
Try 1
$VAR1 = '1425058001.056';
$VAR2 = '7401.7333984375';
$VAR3 = '1425058001.056';

Try 2
$VAR1 = '1425058001.0567';
$VAR2 = '1740.1123046875';
$VAR3 = '1425058001.0567';
```

Note: This is a sample problem.  I realize that there are non-regex based solutions to this problem, and that this problem is fairly trivial, but I hope to gain insight to apply with respect to much more complex parsers implemented similarly in Perl's Regex engine.

Comment: Use `unpack '(N/A)'`

Comment: `/g` makes no sense in `unless ( $text =~ /$parser/g )`, and it causes subtle, hard to debug problems.

Comment: removed the `/g`, it was an artifact of an earlier test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of `(?{ })` and `(??{ })`, don't use lexical vars declared outside the blocks. Use

```
local our @chunks;
local our $chunklen;
```

---

Welcome to the world of closures.

```
sub make_closure {
    my $counter = 0;
    return sub { return ++$counter };
}

my $counter1 = make_closure();
my $counter2 = make_closure();

say $counter1->();  # 1
say $counter1->();  # 2
say $counter1->();  # 3
say $counter2->();  # 1
say $counter2->();  # 2
say $counter1->();  # 4
```

`sub { }` captures lexical variables that are in scope, giving the sub access to them even when the scope in which they exist is gone.

You use this ability every day without knowing it.

```
my $foo = ...;
sub print_foo { print "$foo\n"; }
```

If subs didn't capture, and if they didn't capture at compile-time, the above wouldn't work in a module. The module's sub is likely to be called long after the module finishes executing (longer after `use` is complete), but that's when `$foo` goes away.

You get into trouble when you start placing named subs into other subs.

```
sub outer {
   my ($x) = @_;

   sub inner {
      print("$x\n");
   }

   inner();
}

outer(5);  # 5
outer(6);  # 5!!!
```

`inner` captures `$x` that existed at compile-time. The first call to `outer` will reuse that lexical, but subsequent calls to `outer` will get a fresh `$x`. Perl warns *Variable "$x" will not stay shared*.

Similarly, `(?{ })` and `(??{ })` capture lexicals when they compiled. Since your patterns don't interpolate, they are compiled when the surrounding Perl code is compiled, and capture the lexicals that existed *at that time*. The first call to the sub will reuse those lexicals, but subsequent calls to the sub will get fresh lexicals.

Had you been listening, Perl would have warned you about the problem. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

```
Variable "$chunklen" will not stay shared at (re_eval 2) line 1.
Variable "$chunklen" will not stay shared at (re_eval 3) line 1.
Variable "@chunks" will not stay shared at (re_eval 4) line 1.
```

To solve the inner/outer sub problem, you'd replace what is effectively

```
BEGIN { *inner = sub { ... } }
```

with

```
local *inner = sub { ... };
```

to capture the lexical at run-time. In your case, you can't do that, so you switch to using package variables. Package variables aren't captured but looked up at run-time.

---

As an aside, all you need is

```
my $text = pack '(N/A)*', @samples;
```

and

```
my @samples = unpack '(N/A)*', $text;
```

For example,

```
$ perl -E'
   my @samples = ( "abc", "defg", "hij" );
   my $text = pack "(N/A)*", @samples;
   say uc unpack "H*", $text;
   @samples = unpack "(N/A)*", $text;
   say for @samples;
'
0000000361626300000004646566670000000368696A
abc
defg
hij
```

Comment: This also worked (inspired by the info you gave me): `our ($chunklen, @chunks) = (0);`

Comment: Removing the `local` does not "also work". It makes your code clobber similarly named variables in the caller.

Comment: I would prefer not to use package variables where avoidable.  I see the issue with `our` (reading docs), perhaps `state ($chunklen, @chunks); $chunklen = 0; @chunks = ();` is more what I was looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that should work too (as long as your sub isn't re-entrant (and it's not))

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami), whose answer will remain accepted because it gets at the heart of the matter.  For this example, the solution was as simple as switching from `my` to `state`, and resetting the value.  As [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) explained, when the regular expression was compiled, it captured, as a closure, the lexical variables required for it to function, i.e. that first call's values for `@chunks` and `$chunklen`.  When it was called subsequent times, the regular expression ignored the new lexical variables declared with `my` and continued updating the variables defined in the first call.

As such, switching to `state` preserves those variables across all calls to the subroutine, so the regular expression is referring to the same values as the calling function.  Then, all that was necessary was to reset the values on each call (otherwise, `@chunks` would contain not only chunks found this round, but also, all chunks found on previous calls).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw/ time /;
use Data::Dumper;
use v5.10;

sub parse($) {
    my ( $text ) = @_;

    # vvvv there vvvv
    state ($chunklen, @chunks);
    $chunklen = 0;               # <-- here
    @chunks = ();
    # ^^^^ there ^^^^
    my $parser = qr/
        ^ (?:
            (.{4})                          (?{ ($chunklen) = unpack( 'N', $^N ) })
            ((??{ qr~.{$chunklen}~s }))     (?{ push @chunks, $^N })
        )+ $
    /xs;

    unless ( $text =~ $parser ) {
        die 'bad parse';
    }

    return @chunks;
}

for ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    print "Try $_\n";
    my @samples = ( time, rand(10000), time );
    my $string  = pack 'NA*' x scalar @samples, map { length($_), $_ } @samples;
    print Dumper parse $string;
    print "\n";
}
```

Produces

```
Try 1
$VAR1 = '1425063869.37065';
$VAR2 = '5458.984375';
$VAR3 = '1425063869.37065';

Try 2
$VAR1 = '1425063869.37124';
$VAR2 = '9147.03369140625';
$VAR3 = '1425063869.37124';
```

### Edit: Note the importance of "use v5.10" in this example

Comment: Even though you accepted another answer this seems like a good  "follow up self response" format - since adding this detail may have distracted from your original question.  If I do this I might note the followup response in own question as well (e.g. "see below for follow up").

Comment: ++ for explaining `state` nicely in this case :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have added the note about the follow-up to the head of the question.